# getting youtube video surface texture onto a graphical surface

Tags: android, youtube, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediaplayer, android-youtube-api

I am developing on Android using OpenGL ES 2.0 with shaders to render 3D environment. Before, I was able to use Android Media Player and create a surface, using texture id for the shader as the surface which can be passed into the media player. Video frames played by the media player are now textures for the surface

Currently I am doing something similar but with the youtube-android api where I do the same thing as above but with youtube videos. The youtube api doesn't seem to be as open as the media player for me to do the same things...

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to make something like that. Have you found a solution?